# What is this on stray cat’s skin?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, infections, hairloss

This is a stray cat that I already neutered. He doesn’t live in my building, but I feed him whenever he’s around.

These are some pictures of his skin. I have no idea what it is, but it’s spreading.

Is there anything I can give him to stop that from spreading? It looks like some type of nasty infection.

He’s a stray cat so I can’t pick him up and take him to the vet. And he’ll probably run away if I spray something on him. I’m almost sure that he’s always licking that.

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: How did the vet neuter the cat, if you can not bring it to the vet?

Comment: I’m afraid that you won’t be able to treat this without regular applications of medication and possibly surgery (to remove severely infected areas) and that means a) catching him for a vet visit and b) keeping him confined for a certain time.

Comment: @Allerleirauh: I caught him when he was still a kitten. He's an adult cat.

Answer (score 7):

**I'm not a vet, so this is not professional advice.**

From the pictures, these look like seriously infected wounds that urgently need treatment, these will not heal on their own and likely get worse quickly if left untreated.

Apart from this obvious problem, the coat condition of this cat alone would warrant a vet checkup if you ask me.

As Stephie points out in the comments, the cat will likely need at least regular, uninterrupted medication (antibiotics, the treatment can make matters worse if interrupted!) over a period of time, which in itself is not very feasible for a stray.

Looking at the wounds, it will likely need to wear a cone for some time to give the wounds a chance to heal properly once treatment is started, again not feasible for a stray.

In my lay opinion, this cat needs to be caught and brought to a vet.

---

If the cat does not allow you to pick him up, the best course of action would be to contact a local TNR (trap-neuter-return) group, they usually have traps available they can lend you, and the experienced people to set them up properly as to not harm the cat in the process.